# Does Finasteride reduce hair loss?

Tags: medical-science, medications, hair

Several doctors told me by that taking Finasteride (AKA Proscar or Propecia), I have a better-than-even chance of reducing hair loss.
This [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finasteride) cites one study the corroborates this claim, but it leaves some important questions unanswered. 
For example: Was the study conducted by someone affiliated with a pharmaceutical company? Is it possible that other studies, that had different conclusions, have been conducted but not published?

Can anyone cite more reliable information about this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Separate studies are conducted on men and woman.

[Long-term treatment with finasteride 1 mg decreases the likelihood of developing further visible hair loss in men with androgenetic alopecia (male pattern hair loss)](http://www.jle.com/fr/revues/ejd/e-docs/long_term_treatment_with_finasteride_1_mg_decreases_the_likelihood_of_developing_further_visible_hair_loss_in_men_with_androgen_278087/article.phtml) European Journal of Dermatology, vol. 18, pages 400-20 reports:

> Finasteride 1 mg treatment led to a 93% decrease relative to placebo in the 5-year likelihood of developing further visible hair loss (95% CI: 89-97%; p < 0.001). We conclude that, in men with AGA, treatment with finasteride 1 mg/day over 5 years led to a marked and sustained decrease in the likelihood of developing further visible hair loss.

However, see also: [Persistent sexual, emotional, and cognitive impairment post-finasteride: a survey of men reporting symptoms](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24928450) American Journal of Men's Health vol. 9, pages 222-228.